# iPhone screen degraded performance - evident when using Maps

Tags: iphone, screen

I have an iPhone 5s and I have the following issue: after a while, the screen gets progressively less responsive and horizontal and vertical stripes appear. Things are much worse if I use the phone while moving (especially when using Maps) than if I'm at home or at the office.

Is this behaviour indicative of a screen problem or of something else like a motherboard fault?

In the attached pictures, you can see the typical striped pattern.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Hi, can you clarify whether these stripes are white, grey, or coloured? Also, are the stripes always present, or just when your phone becomes less responsive? Finally, what happens if you do a full reboot?

Comment: @Monomeeth the stripes are coloures, and placed around the objects in the screen (see the images added to the question). If the phone is idle, the stripes are not visible; they become more and more evident as you use the phone. Pressing the home button makes things momentarily better. In the worst case, there are stripes and the screen is not responsive. No stripes are visible after a reboot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've seen a few iPhones with vertical lines over the years, but can't recall if I've ever seen one with horizontal lines.

Firstly, just to get this out of the way, I assume this is the original screen? I have seen strange behaviour such as this when non-genuine screens have been used. If you have a non-genuine screen, this could very well be your problem.

Assuming it is a genuine screen, the first thing to try (because it's easy to do) is a full reboot of your phone. By this I mean simultaneously holding down the power and Home buttons until you see the Apple logo on your screen.

If a full reboot doesn't work, then the next thing to try is to manually do a full backup of your iPhone (via iTunes on your Mac/PC) and then restore the iPhone from that backup. This process resets your iPhone to default settings and can erase any firmware glitches.

Finally, if none of the above explains or resolves the issue, then it's going to be a hardware issue. This *could* be a faulty/damaged display, but may also just be a loose connection. You're best bet is to take it into Apple or some other repairer to look at.

Comment: I followed the steps you suggested, and the lines are still there. I'm now downgrading to iOS 10 and afterwards I'll bring it to a shop to check the screen and the connections.

Comment: If you're on iOS 11 then there's no way to downgrade to iOS 10. I would just take it into a repairer to look at. All the best with it!